# Problems converting C# UNC path conversion code to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, unc

I have a function in a C# application which is perfect for a VB.net application that I need to extend.

The function takes a path which could be a local folder or a network share, and if it's a network drive it returns a full UNC path e.g. `P:\MyProject` might resolve to `\\server8\Projects\MyProject`

The C# code, which works fine and includes

```
using System.Management;
```

looks like this:

```
public string GetUNCPath(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                if (path.StartsWith(@"\\"))
                {
                    return path;
                }

                ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject();
                mo.Path = new ManagementPath(String.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", path));

                // DriveType 4 = Network Drive
                if (Convert.ToUInt32(mo["DriveType"]) == 4)
                {
                    return Convert.ToString(mo["ProviderName"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    return path;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // If it fails, just return the original path
                return path;
            }
        }
```

I have tried to convert it to VB.net but am out of my depth with the syntax (see below). My converted code compiles OK but if I isolate the code and step through it, the calls to `Convert.ToUInt32(mo("DriveType"))` and `Convert.ToString(mo("ProviderName"))` both throw an exception of `{"Not found"}`.

Where am I going wrong? BTW, I'm a complete novice so where possible please provide instructions that a 5 year old could follow :-)

The VB.net which includes:

`Imports System.Management`

looks like this

```
Private Function GetUNCPath(sPath As String) as string
    Try
        If sPath.StartsWith("\\") Then Return sPath

        Dim mo As New ManagementObject
        mo.Path = New ManagementPath(String.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", sPath))

        If Convert.ToUInt32(mo("DriveType")) = 4 Then
            Return Convert.ToString(mo("ProviderName"))
        Else
            Return sPath
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        '' If it fails, just return the original path
        Return sPath
    End Try
End Function
```

Just to double check what is happening I created a mount on my machine so that I now have a path P:\Project X and then I put together the following test function which uses `Imports System.Management`

```
Private Sub TestingGetUNCPath()
    Try
        Dim mo As New ManagementObject
        mo.Path = New ManagementPath(String.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", "P:\Project X"))

        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToUInt32(mo("DriveType"))).ToString()
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(mo("ProviderName")))

    Catch ex As Exception
        '' If it fails, just return the original path
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have tried this with the `P:\Project X folder` and with `C:\temp` and trying both of the MessageBox calls separately. All variations throw the `Not found` exception

Comment: What is a ManagementObject?  Better yet.. please put all IMPORT statements in your code samples.  And better yet, post your PackageReferences from your csproj/vbproj files.

Comment: You don't need to convert it to VB. Extract the C# code to a class library project (if it's not one already), build that, and reference it in the VB project.

Comment: The System.IO.Path class can work with UNC paths. Use it, someone has figured out all the edge cases

Comment: @granadaCoder I'm going to take a wild guess that it's `System.Management.ManagementObject`.

Comment: Ha!  You're right.  But it's a good practice of the question-asker to put this information in their question(s), rather than having everyone "guess".

Comment: Have you tried stepping through both codes to see if there is an obvious divergence somewhere?  They look identical to me, but the error message suggests that there might be a difference in the path you used to initialize the ManagementObject.

Comment: This isn't your main problem, but why are you returning 'Object' in the VB version when the C# version clearly returns string?

Comment: I just tested both your code snippets with "Z:" on my local machine and got the correct UNC path on both occasions. I would suggest that you are feeding the wrong path or else you haven't referenced the correct library. Note that I tested against both .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 6.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I have updated the original question to include the Imports/Using of System.Management and have ensured that the VB version returns a string!  I am indeed stepping through the code and whether the drive is a network on or a local one, it still throws an exception so I don't understand how user18387401 got it to work

Comment: I have now created the TestingGetUNCPath() sub (see updated code) and this throws the same exception regardless of the path presented to it.